# Modifying the logic around the global variables in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new to BigCommerce platform.I came to know that the global variables in big commerce got its values from the logic that comes from PHP classes from somewhere **includes/classes folder**.

My problem is I couldn't get access to those files.I want to know whether i can get access to those files,if yes than how?

Actually i wanted to use my logic on product option.On inspection i found out that it is rendering from this global variable.

> %%GLOBAL_ProductAttributeList%%

Till now i only could modify the template files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Bigcommerce, they have multiple variables, GLOBAL, PANEL, and SNIPPET to name a few. If a variable is GLOBAL, then you can't access that little piece of code. Sometimes a GLOBAL variable is just text, where you can delete that variable and simply enter the text you want to say instead. However, if a GLOBAL variable contains logic, then there's really nothign you can do. Bigcommerce doesn't allow you to see their GLOBAL or to use any server sided code (PHP, SQL, etc).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for reply, my question is if we can't access the php or other than how can we implement our logic?

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking to accomplish. If this is for user experience or is front end only you can use javascript. If this impacts price, inventory, or any backend functionality then you can only accomplish via the Bigcommerce backend. I'd need to know more to let you know if possible and how.

Comment: @aton1004 unfortunately, that's one of the big problems with bigcommerce. The amount of logic you can use is virtually zero. However, there are options, rules, and many other aspects in the bigcommerce backend that can do a lot of the logic for you. Like what developerscott said, what exactly are you trying to accomplish/modify?

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks Jonathan and developerscott for the help.